# Error (ionic run android) on windows 8 Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

`Using this version of Cordova with older version of cordova-android is being deprecated. Consider upgrading to cordova-android@5.0.0 or newer.`

Running command: `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\xampp\htdocs\aim\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:/xampp/htdocs/aim
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\xampp\htdocs\aim\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat"`
`Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT`

Answer (score 29):

run `cordova platform update android`. The problem should be solved.